# PostgreSQL first time install and attempt to connect

Tags: installation, postgresql-9.1

I just installed postgresql-9.1.4-1-windows-x64 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  I'm having trouble starting the service and connecting to a database. 
After a successful installation I've tried the following based on similar postings.

1)  Looked for "Start Server" under Start > All Programs > PostreSQL 9.1 and could not find it.

2)  Tried starting the server from the command line

```
pg_ctl.exe -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\data"
```

This gave me the error:

```
could not create lock file 'postmaster.pid': Permission denied
```

I have administrative rights, and there is not postmaster.pid file either in the bin or data directories.

3)  Next I tried starting the Service from Admistrative Tools by right clicking on the postgresql-9.1.4-1-windows-x64 Service and selecting Start.  I received the message:

> The postgresql-9.1.4-1-windows-x64 Service on local computer started
>   and stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they are not in use
>   by other services or programs.

The Event Viewer showed the error as `Timed out waiting for server startup`

4) I figured there the data in the data directory was probably and initial database, but just in case I ran "initdb" and got:

> If you want to create a new database system either remove or empty the
>   directory c:\program files\postgreSql/9.1/data or run initdb with an
>   argument other than c:\program files\postgreSql/9.1/data

4) And just for fun I Started pgAdminIII, right clicked on  "PostreSQL 9.1(localhost:5432)", selected Connect, entered password, and got:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Was this installed using the "one click" installer from EnterpriseDB? If so, I have generally seen them recommend looking at the contents of the installer log files, which I think are in the temp directory.

Comment: Yes, it was the one click installer.  Are you referring to the Windows\temp directory?  Couldn't find anything that looked like it came from this install and there is no temp dir under the PostgreSQL program directory.

Comment: The directory to check is the one specified by `%TEMP%` for the user under which the install process is running.

Answer (score 2):

> «"could not create lock file 'postmaster.pid': Permission denied"»

Do not look any further, Postgres cannot start if it can't create this temp file. If it is not created, you evidently cannot find it if you look for it on the disk. Your DATA directory has been created so no need to re run `initdb` again and if you try to use pgadmin it complains that it cannot connect to Pg -- which is not running.

I am not familiar with windows but found out where `postmaster.pid` is to be created you will probably find out why Postgres cannot create this file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I must be blind; I missed that message in the question entirely. I've edited the question to set off the quoted messages better. This is definitely it. Good spot.